# SQL - Constructing regex for SELECT with the results of a subquery SELECT?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am finding myself in a situation like this.

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
TableA
ID  Name
1   First
2   Second
3   Third
...
```

I have a second table that looks something like this:

```
TableB
ID   Name
...
95   Fifth
96   First
97   First121
98   Third9
99   1Second22
100  Fourth
...
```

I am trying to figure out how to locate exactly any record in TABLE B that follows the following format:
^[Substring in TABLE A][0-9]*

Therefore, records 97 and 98 should be in the results set. If 96 and 99 are in there, I can deal with it, but ideally I'd rather not.

Essentially, I am trying to figure out how to use a WHERE IN/JOIN syntax to find records in Table B that are in TABLE, but to use that results set as part of a regex expression.

Because I am using this in a Javascript context with the node.js sqlite library, I could theoretically return all matches and manually construct a chain of WHERE statements with placeholders based on the return of a previous query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableB
WHERE name REGEXP '^(?)[0-9]*' OR
      name REGEXP '^(?)[0-9]*' OR
```

With one (?) placeholder for each value in Table A. I'd like to know if it's possible to do this in one statement, as this feels extremely clunky. Ideally I'm shooting for something like this, but it wouldn't work as is:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableB
WHERE name REGEXP '^(SELECT ...)[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists` or `join`:

```
select b.*
from b
where exists (select 1
              from tablea a
              where b.name regexp concat(a.name, '[0-9]*')
             );
```

This how *you* specified the regular expression.  If you don't want `'First'`, then use:

```
where exists (select 1
              from tablea a
              where b.name regexp concat('^', a.name, '[0-9]+')
             );
```